# str_replace() not working correctly

Tags: php, str-replace

I've been having this issue for a few hours, and I can't seem to figure out what it could be.

I currently have an Administration Panel script that allows Admins to post blogs on the main website, and I have a line that is utilizing str_replace();

```
foreach($_FILES["images"]["tmp_name"] AS $index => $tmpName)
{
     //replace in body
     $Body = str_replace("[" . $index + 1 . "]", "<img src=\"/images/gallery/" . $seoTitle . "/" . $_FILES["images"]["name"][$index] . "\" />", $Body);
```

Currently, when writing a blog post, I allow images to be uploaded, and while the script is processing each image, it'll replace a tag such as [1] [2] (it's image index + 1) with the actual img tag.

I had the script output the parsed Body and it returned something around

```
This is body content [<img src="/images/gallery/asdasdasdasd/windows.png">
```

As you can see, the image has a open bracket right before the image tag starts for an odd reason.

I haven't been able to find a solution for some reason. Has this ever happened to anyone else?

Thanks,
Jacob

As Dave commented that the problem could be within another part of the code, the entire POST process is below:

```
if(isset($_POST["create"]))
{
    $Title = trim($_POST["title"]);
    $Body = trim($_POST["body"]);
    $seoTitle = seo($Title);
    if($Title == "" || $Body == "")
    {
        $Template->assign_var("error", "Dude, fill in all of the fields.");
    }
        else
    {
        if(!empty($_FILES["images"]))
        {
            $allowed_types = array("image/gif", "image/jpeg", "image/jpg", "image/pjpeg", "image/x-png", "image/png");
            $allowed_ext = array("jpg", "jpeg", "gif", "png");
            $photos = array();

            if(!is_dir(ROOT_DIR . "../images/gallery/" . $seoTitle))
                mkdir(ROOT_DIR . "../images/gallery/" . $seoTitle);
            foreach($_FILES["images"]["tmp_name"] AS $index => $tmpName)
            {
                $filedata = explode(".", $_FILES["images"]["name"][$index]);
                $ext = end($filedata);
                if(in_array($ext, $allowed_ext) && in_array($_FILES["images"]["type"][$index], $allowed_types))
                {
                    move_uploaded_file($tmpName, ROOT_DIR . "../images/gallery/" . $seoTitle . "/" . $_FILES["images"]["name"][$index]);
                    //replace photo in body
                    $Body = str_replace("[" . $index + 1 . "]", "<img class=\"blog_photo\" src=\"/images/gallery/" . $seoTitle . "/" . $_FILES["images"]["name"][$index] . "\" />", $Body);
                    $photos[] = $_FILES["images"]["name"][$index];
                }
            }
            $Template->assign_var("error", $Body);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `$index + 1` What is the purpose of this?

Comment: What does `$Body` look like?

Comment: $index + 1 is because the first image returned has an index of 0, though the user should be able to type in [1] to obtain the first image.

$Body is a $_POST variable that is typed in like: "This is body content [1]"

Comment: obviously the error is with code which is not posted here.

Comment: Entire POST block has been added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Evidently, the issue is indeed strange, thought it is made due to parentheses not being used when doing $index + 1.

So changing the code to the following:

```
$Body = str_replace("[" . ($index + 1) . "]", "<img class=\"blog_photo\" src=\"/images/gallery/" . $seoTitle . "/" . $_FILES["images"]["name"][$index] . "\" />", $Body);
```

will indeed work.

Answer (score 0):

use this to findout where is the problem and compare output

```
print_r($_FILES["images"]["tmp_name"]);
echo "<br />";

foreach($_FILES["images"]["tmp_name"] AS $index => $tmpName)
{
     //replace in body
     $Body = str_replace("[" . $index + 1 . "]", "<img src=\"/images/gallery/" . $seoTitle . "/" . $_FILES["images"]["name"][$index] . "\" />", $Body);

    echo "[" . $index + 1 . "]" . "<br />";
    echo "<img src=\"/images/gallery/" . $seoTitle . "/" . $_FILES["images"]["name"][$index] . "\" />";
}
```

Comment: The following was returned: Array([0] => C:\Windows\Temp\phpD7F1.tmp)<br />1]<br /><img src="/images/gallery/asfadgfusnhufgg/hostr-logo.png" />   That's odd that it was returned, because when I changed the echo "[" . $index + 1"]"; to echo "[[[" . $index + 1 . "]";, the same thing was returned. Nothing was changed.